# Is there a category in which, between any two objects, there is a unique morphism?

Tags: category-theory

I am interested in knowing information about such a category (if it is well-defined).

Does there exist a category $\mathcal{C}$, in which there is a unique morphism between any two objects in it?

Comment: I changed the question and removed the tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes;

- A category in which there is at most one arrow between any two objects is just a poset.
- A category in which there is precisely one arrow between any two objects is just a boolean.

I work up to equivalence, of course.

**Edit.** Here's a simple way of getting a boolean $\mathrm{isInhab}(X)$ from a set $X$, which expresses the proposition "$X$ is inhabited."

- The object set of $\mathrm{isInhab}(X)$ is just $X$.
- The arrow set of $\mathrm{isInhab}(X)$ is $X \times X$.
- The codomain of $(y,x)$ is $y$ and the domain of $(y,x)$ is $x$.
- We define $\mathrm{id}_x = (x,x)$ for each $x \in X$.
- We compose ordered pairs by "cutting" the middle value: $$(z,y) \circ (y,x) = (z,x).$$

Up to equivalence, $\mathrm{isInhab}(X)$ will be "true" if $X$ is inhabited, and "false" if $X$ is the empty set.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It's indeed not so accurate. A poset is supposed to be a set! So a poset is the same as a **small** category with at most one arrow between any two objects.

Comment: @YCor, imo the best conventions are that words like set, ring, group, category, etc. are interpreted in the widest possible sense. So for example, I consider the surreal numbers to be a ring, the cardinal numbers to be a semiring, and the set of all formal $\mathbb{R}$-linear combinations of ordinals to be an abelian group. We can then use the adjective "small" as needed; for instance, under these conventions, $\mathbb{R}$ is a small set, whereas the set of ordinal numbers is not.

Comment: so you define a "small set" as a set whose elements form a small set? :)

Comment: @YCor, no. Have a look at any introduction to "algebraic set theory" (it's more interesting than it sounds) for a nice account of proper classes. Basically, a set $X$ is \textit{small} iff the function $X \rightarrow 1$ is small, where $1$ is the set with $1$ element. So basically, the notion of a small function precedes that of a small set.

Comment: @YCor Why must such a category satisfy the antisymmetric property? Shouldn't it be just a preorder?

Comment: @suitangi poset means partially ordered set, not partially preordered set.

Comment: @YCor yes, and therefore a poset satisfies the antisymmetric property. But I don't see why "a category in which there is at most one arrow between any two objects" must satisfy the antisymmetric property.

Comment: @YCor In brief, my claim is that a category in which there is at most one arrow between any two objects is not a poset but a preordered set.

Comment: @suitangi oh, yes you're right (at least for a small category). Whether a category where objects don't form a set, with at most one arrow between any two objects, is a preposet, is a matter of convention, apparently.

Answer (score 5):

A category $\mathcal{C}$ in which every hom-set has exactly one element is necessarily a **groupoid** since the unique morphism $p:A\to B$ and the unique morphism $q:B\to A$ must compose to the morphism $\mathrm{id}_A:A\to A$ and $\mathrm{id}_B:B\to B$.

Moreover, $\mathcal{C}$ is a **connected** groupoid since every two objects of the category have a morphism between them.

Lastly, $\mathcal{C}$ is a **thin category**, since every hom-set has *at most one* element.

So, we could call such a category a thin, connected groupoid.

---

Such a category is completely determined by its objects, since the requirements for the morphisms are so strict. Any example of such a category is just going to be a set (or class) of objects, to which the necessary unique-morphism-between-any-objects have been added.

The simplest example, then, is the empty category $\mathbf{0}$ (no objects, no morphisms), and the next simplest example after that is the terminal category $\mathbf{1}$ (one object $\ast$, and only $\mathrm{id}_{\ast}:\ast\to\ast$).

Answer (score 0):

Given a continuous flow f on a locally compact Hausdorff space X, call a
subset S of X an f-invariant set if S is the union of orbits of the flow f. Call S f-isolated if, with respect to the partial order defined by
inclusion, S is the largest f-invariant set contained in some compact
neighborhood N of S; e.g., the critical elements of a Morse-Smale vector
field on a manifold are isolated relative to the flow generated
by the vector field. The Conley index of an f-isolated invariant set is a
1-connected groupoid (i.e., there is exactly one morphism from A to B for
any ordered pair (A,B) of objects of the groupoid) that is a small
subcategory of the homotopy category of pointed compact Hausdorff spaces.
Conley calls such groupoids connected simple systems. The Conley index is
particularly useful in finding bifurcation orbits, e.g., heteroclinic
orbits between two critical elements. See

1. H.L. Kurland, The Morse index of an isolated invariant set is a
   connected simple system, J.~Differential Equations 42 (1981), 234--259.
2. C.C. Conley, Isolated Invariant Sets and the Morse Index, CBMS
   Conference Proceedings, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R.I., 1978.